# Is it possible to disable a (apparently native) specific Windows Hotkey? aka Customizing a hotkey already defined in Windows

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

As a *convention for myself*, I use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> as a **hotkey prefix** for my **normal user** programs.

For example, I configure the hotkey for the *internet navigator* (Opera in my case) as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>.

This convention is useful for remembering hotkeys: I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> for **management programs** (example: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> for *Temperature Sensors*, AIDA64 in my case)... etc.

But, after installing uTorrent, I have found that my **Windows 7 SP1 doesn't allow** to configure <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> as hotkey; instead, it opens an explorer on the folder where the program is located (?):

[image: Results of pressing Alt+Shift+U]

, and the hotkey gets no recorded in the shortcut properties:

[image: No changes on shortcut]

Of course that I could use another hotkey for my uTorrent, but **learning** about a way to "tame" (also known as "behave as the user wants, rather than as it wants") Windows for this could become useful.

I don't want to disable *the rest of Windows native hotkeys*, because I use them a lot.
So, is there any way to **disable the specific** <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> Windows hotkey behavior in order to configure the mine? Maybe any regedit change?

Comment: You can use AutoHotKey: http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Override.htm

Comment: The suggestion is correct, @shub. You should post it as an answer detailing the steps. If you don't, I will, as a self-answer question.

Comment: Unfortunately I know nothing about AutoHotKey which is why I commented before, in case you knew about it. So feel free to add your own self answer - it will educate me as well!